# spaCy English language module not downloading on Ubuntu

Tags: python

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04.I downloaded spaCy using conda and am working on jupyter notebooks.
I tried downloading the english module using

```
python -m spacy download en
```

which gave me the following error:

> ```
> /home/nikita/anaconda3/bin/python: No module named spacy.__main__; 'spacy' is a package and cannot be directly executed
> ```

So I tried

```
python -m spacy.en.download
```

But that isn't working either.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is discussed and analyzed in detail in the following thread: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2514

If the analysis is correct the following change should have solved it:
https://github.com/explosion/thinc/releases/tag/v6.10.3

Had the same problem. Did not yet try the solution. Will do so tomorrow.

Regards, dsp

Comment: First of all, Welcome to Super User! We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but please [do not provide answers that are only a hyperlink](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). While the information may be valuable, if the source web page ever goes offline the answer is essentially useless. Quote all of the pertinent excerpts from the article within your answer, then you can still provide the hyperlink to cite your source. Please see the following article from our Help Center:  [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Please don't post answers until you have confirmed a working solution.

Comment: It was a bug that sneeked into spaCy because of a change in a dependency msgpack / msgpack-python. Issue was closed in 2018-09-12. Worked for me.